# Setting up RTMP nginx server on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, rtmp

totally new to this, so please don't judge too hard.
Little uni project, trying to set up an RTMP NGINX server within a Ubuntu OS virtual machine on my mac.

Ubuntu OS --> 20.04 LTS

Mac OS --> 10.15.5

I'm following two guides... https://www.nginx.com/blog/video-streaming-for-remote-learning-with-nginx/ and https://www.servermania.com/kb/articles/nginx-rtmp.
For both guides everything works fine until I try to `make`. I get the following error --> [image: make error screenshot]
Prepending `sudo` does not help either.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I get it when it comes to asking why a piece of code doesn't work or the command, yet this is literally just the error message. You can't see any cli command I issued. Maybe I could have posted the commands I issued before this error arose, however the rule you stated does not apply here. What do you want me to do? Type the error message out by hand, I don't even understand what is happening here - I woulnd't know what error message to post... therefore the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/1283#issuecomment-439217412

Add this to the end of your `./configure` command:

```
--with-cc-opt="-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0"
```

then run `make` again